# Default function props in functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

So I'm looking through several SO questions and each example pertains to a Class based component not a functional component.

So I have a Container `ListContainer` that renders `List` and I'm passing `toggleDrawer()`. I'm unable to define `toggleDrawer()` in the `List.defaultProps`

**ListContainer.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import List from './List';

class ListContainer extends Component{
  constructor(props){...}
  const toggleDrawer = () => {...}
  render(){
    return(
      <List data={data} toggleDrawer={toggleDrawer}/>
    )
  }
}

...export statement...
```

**List.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

function List(props){
  const { data, toggleDrawer } = props;
  const openDrawer = () => toggleDrawer();
  const renderListItems = (items) => {//renders a list};

  return(
    <ul>{renderListItems(data)}</ul>
  )
}

List.propTypes = {
  toggleDrawer: PropTypes.func,
};

List.defaultProps = {
  toggleDrawer: <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Not sure how to define toggleDrawer() here
}

...export statement...
```

The problem I'm running into is I've tried using `getDefaultProps()` and maybe it's not being implemented correctly but that hasn't worked. All the examples I've looked at are using State components and so trying to use `.bind(this)` or `this.toggleDrawer.this(bind)` or any of the other examples I've tried aren't working either.

What am I missing here? Or would it be better practice to just have `toggleDrawer: PropTypes.func.isRequired`. That does remove the ESLint error, but I'm not 100% on that function always being required

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you probably want is a noop:

```
List.defaultProps = { toggleDrawer: () => {} };
```

The advantage of this is that you can be sure that `this.props.toggleDrawer` is a function even if no value was specified, which means you can safely call it without checking. Another alternative is to set the default to `null`, and then check that the prop is a function before calling it:

```
if(typeof this.props.toggleDrawer === 'function') { /* call function */ }
```

For the record it doesn't make much sense to define another callback (`openDrawer()`) which simply calls `toggleDrawer`. You may as well just call `toggleDrawer` directly.

Comment: Ok, thought I tried defining it as `toggleDrawer: () => {}` but maybe I was trying that while wrapping in a `getDefaultProps()`. Also thanks for pointers and I removed the `openDrawer()` and everything is working as expected. I thought I needed to created a function that would return a callback to the pass props function. So learned a couple things. Accepting this answer based on more completeness.

Answer (score 3):

Just do:

```
List.defaultProps = {
  toggleDrawer: function () {
    // enter code here 
  }
}
```

or arrow functions:

```
List.defaultProps = {
  toggleDrawer: () => {
    // enter code here 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this works. A bit perplexed on I thought I had tried this but apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write like this concise style :

```
List.defaultProps = { 
  toggleDrawer() {} 
};
```